# How to pass huge string data from javascript to java action class?

Tags: java, javascript, struct

Is that possible to pass huge string data from javascript to java action class?

```
var url = "xwe.action?pdfDivContent=" + encodeURIComponent(div1);
    alert( url);
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.send(null)
```

I tired the above code and it is not working as pdfDivContent is huge in size(#approx 2000 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the data via GET not post. You should be putting the data in send, not the querystring. This is assuming that `div1` actually holds a string.

```
var url = "xwe.action";
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.send("pdfDivContent=" + encodeURIComponent(div1))
```

---

Based on your comment, maybe you need to set these headers

```
var url = "xwe.action";
req.open("POST", url, true);
var params = "pdfDivContent=" + encodeURIComponent(div1);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
req.send(params);
```

Comment: I can get into the action class but the pdfDivContent is null.

Comment: And you are sure that `div1` has content. Do you see content in the post request when you inspect it with the console? Also added another thing for you to try.